# Invoice automatically created when i am placing an prepaid(Razor Pay) order in magento 2.2.7?

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice

Can any one help me on this, When I am placing a prepaid order in magento, the invoice gets generated automatically. Before it was I manually created an invoice but now it's automatically genrated,what happened here I don't know. Is this is due to any configuration changes? please answer on this.

Comment: Which payment method do you use?

Comment: I am using RazorPay

Comment: Check from system config Payment Action value, If its set Authorize and Capture then invoice will create automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was posted in comments by @Sohel Rana.

In Magento Admin, check from system config Payment Action value, If its set **Authorize and Capture** then an invoice will create automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What does "system config Payment Action value" even mean ? Back end ? There is no config in system.